# EJB 2.0 stubs are not being created in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, ejb, rad

I tried to build stub files in eclipse luna and oxygen by clicking on "**prepare for deployment**" button under JavaEE Tools but nothing is happening.

But, stubs are being generated in RAD 8.5.

I am using `websphere 8.5` with `JRE 1.7`.

Files I have-

1) a web project

2) an EJB project

3) An EAR to deploy it on websphere.

I tried to use `ejbdeploy.bat` but couldn't.

Are there any other way to create stubs? Or if I have to run `ejbdeploy.bat` then what syntax should I run ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse (Luna, Oxygen, whatever) doesn't know how to generate EJB stubs for WebSphere. There is no single way to generate stubs for EJB's; it is up to the Application Server vendor to provide this functionality to Eclipse via a plugin.

When you're using RAD, you have this functionality as IBM ships WAS tooling with the product.

If you absolutely need these stubs, then you'll have to use `ejbdeploy.bat` to generate them.

Most likely you don't need any stubs. Any currently-supported version of WebSphere Application Server can function just fine with no stubs pre-generated whatsoever.